# Android - Using thread on image processing

Tags: java, android, multithreading, image-processing

I try to change all pixel value. To do this, I subtract 10 from each pixel value. This task is too long for my images(720x1200). So, I want to use multi-thread. I write a code that uses threads and calculates new pixel values.

```
/* Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //func one or whatever
            Date interestingDate = null;
            long diffT = 0;
            interestingDate = new Date();
        */  for( int y = 0; y < temp.height()/2; y++ ) { 
                for( int x = 0; x < temp.width(); x++ ) {
                    for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
                    {
                        double values[] = temp.get(y, x);
                        values[0] = values[0] - 10;
                        values[1] = values[1] - 10;
                        values[2] = values[2] - 10;
                        temp.put(y, x, values);
                    }
                }
            }
     /*       Date end = new Date();
            diffT = end.getTime() - interestingDate.getTime();
            Log.i(TAG, "diffT = " + diffT);
        }
    });
    t1.start();
```

Main thread gets 3 value using `temp.get(y,x)`, but t1 thread gets only one value. I discover this when I use debugger to detect run time `outOfArray` error.

How can I get all pixel values(r-g-b) from the image using threads? I don't add any code to wait thread. Should I do?

If I use `AsyncTasks`, Can my application run without available internet? [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) says that

> Create a new Android project called de.vogella.android.asynctask with an activity called ReadWebpageAsyncTask. Add the android.permission.INTERNET permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: If you are able to use Java 7, does this tutorial on using [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) help you? This example looks quite similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I edit my question. Do you have an idea about my second question?